# I set up a remote node for moneroworld.com 3 days ago but I'm not seeing it in the DNS

Tags: remote-access, nodes

I followed the instructions here https://moneroworld.com/#contribute and set up a remote node and tested tested my ports and it looks like it's working but when I check the dns for node.moneroworld.com I'm not seeing my nodes IP listed.  The node I set up is node.xmrlotto.com(65.19.181.20):18089

Any help would be appreciated!